# Using a variable from a file in a loop

Tags: perl

I bumped my head on this piece of code for two days without any success:
What I need to do is obtain a list of IP addresses starting from a long list of NETWORKS in this format:

NETWORK NUMBER_OF_HOSTS
192.168.1.0 512

I've found this bunch of code in the Net:IP module that seems perfect for my needs:

```
my $ip = new Net::IP ('192.168.1.0 + 512');
        do {
             print $ip->ip(), "\n";
        } while (++$ip);
```

With the NETWORK and HOST value declared explicitly the snippet works flawlessly, when I use it inside a while loop passing the data through variables, the problems start.
After many tries I've modified the list as follows:

'192.168.150.0 + 512'

And this is the resulting script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::IP;

open(MYFILE, "ips.txt") or die "$0: Can't open input file $input: $!\n";

while (<MYFILE>){

        chomp $_;
        my $ip = new Net::IP ($_);
        do {
             print $ip->ip(), "\n";
        } while (++$ip);
}

close(MYFILE);
```

When I try to execute it gives me the following error:

> Can't call method "ip" on an undefined value at ./iplist.pl line 14,
>    line 1.

If I print the variable inside the while loop with this `print $_,"\n";` it prints the variable correctly, so where am I wrong? Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE1:
od output for ips.txt

```
0000000   '   4   1   .   5   7   .   1   1   6   .   0       +       1
0000020   0   2   4   '  \n   '   4   1   .   5   7   .   1   9   2   .
0000040   0       +       1   6   3   8   4   '  \n   '   4   1   .   6
0000060   6   .   1   9   2   .   0       +       1   6   3   8   4   '
0000100  \n   '   4   1   .   7   4   .   8   0   .   0       +       4
0000120   0   9   6   '  \n   '   4   1   .   7   5   .   4   8   .   0
0000140       +       4   0   9   6   '  \n   '   4   1   .   7   6   .
0000160   2   4   .   0       +       2   0   4   8   '  \n   '   4   1
0000200   .   7   7   .   6   4   .   0       +       2   0   4   8   '
0000220  \n   '   4   1   .   7   8   .   4   0   .   0       +       1
0000240   0   2   4   '  \n
```

Comment: Nits aside, the program is fine. The error must be in the input file. What's the output of `od -c ips.txt`?

Comment: @ikegami I've added the first lines of the od output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *string literal* (i.e. *Perl code*)

```
'192.168.1.0 + 512'
```

produces the *string*

```
192.168.1.0 + 512
```

As for `readline` (`<$fh>`), it produces a line of the file. Ignoring the newline you chomp away, it returns the string

```
'192.168.1.0 + 512'
```

This differs from the earlier string in that it has extra quotes. Remove the quotes from the file.